# Django update api

Tags: python, django, patch

I ma creating a user profile update api via django:

in urls:

```
url(r'^/api/users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)$', UserView.as_view(), name='user_profile'),
```

And my view:

```
class UserView(APIView):
    def patch(self, request, user_id):
        # logging.info('user Id: %s' % user_id)
        logging.info('in patch...')
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

why patch def not called at all?! (I get 504 method not allowed)

my request is:

patch > http://localhost:8000/api/users/2

When i'm deleting the `user_id` argument in view, it works, but i need to get the user id in path.

Comment: Please show signature of UserView  class.

Comment: @PrashantGaur See the updated question.

Comment: try  this def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):   try to get user_id from kwargs.get .  let me know if still issue exist.  Please django rest framework as tag , it seems like you are using DRF.

Comment: (maybe dumb question here) are you sure you're calling the endpoint using a PATCH method and not doing a POST? the error message is quite explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def patch(self, request, user_id):
    # logging.info('user Id: %s' % user_id)
    logging.info('in patch...')
    user = User.objects.get(id=2)
    serializer = UserSerializer(instance=user, data=request.data, partial=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

You must provide instance eq: `serializer = UserSerializer(instance=user, data=request.data, partial=True)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to relate to the problem the OP is having.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
class UserView(APIView):
    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # try to get user_id from kwargs.get('user_id', None)
```